# Cocoapods, what happens if repo is deleted?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I started using cocoapods a few months ago and glossed over the scenario where a repo was deleted. Today I'm having an issue which breaks my build. Although this isn't due to a deleted repo.

I've been reading that you can commit your pod folder to local git, which to be honest would only be for backup purposes.

What would I do if a repo was deleted. If I run `pod update` this will break my build.

Should I keep copies of my pod folder, if so how? To be honest I'm not sure if I could copy sub folders? I'm just wondering if could have a different/safer setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options to prevent or respond to a deleted repo:

- You have a local copy in your Pods directory, and if it is deleted possibly in your backups that you can move to a private repo or into the project.
- You can indeed commit or back up your Pods directory. I do not prefer to commit it because your repo would now not be focused on your own app.
- If a pod is no longer supported, I would consider replacing it immediately. If your project depends on unmaintained open source and you are unwilling to maintain it yourself, it is going to be a problem eventually, for example when iOS is updated and things your library uses are deprecated. If nothing else, you have lost the community leverage that the open source provided you in the first place.
- You can maintain your own private or public versions of each pod by forking each of their repos. Whenever you want to upgrade them, you'll need to pull updates to each repo. I have done this for clients with build servers that can not see the internet, and it would also meet your concern, with a lot of effort. https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

Comment: OK, I guess then I could just archive / zip the pod folder and unzip / replace if I had a problem?

Comment: Yes. You could potentially pull out individual pods from that backup, remove them from your podfile, and configure them manually. I'm going to edit to add a 4th option, which is to maintain private versions of all pods.